# How to remove double quote from array string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting the array in this form `"['5', '6', '12']"` and I want to remove the double quote and get this array `['5', '6', '12']` in this form.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `your_string[1...-1]` should be enough.

Comment: Where are you getting this string from and what have you tried? If you could add some context that would be great - it would make it a lot easier for others to help get a solution :)

Comment: Getting this "'5', '6', '12'" instead of this ['5', '6', '12']

Comment: Srack- I am getting this string in params.

Comment: Ok, now I get it, you want to convert string into an array, right?

Comment: Thanks Umesh - I'd suggest having a look at your form then, to ensure the data comes through directly and avoid having to convert. Might be useful to update your question to reflect this and include the code for the form itself.

Comment: It's an angular + rails based application so I can't change the front end part... I have to handle the given params.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the actual input you've provided (i.e. not valid JSON), this won't quite work...

But usually, what I *expect* the correct answer to be in situations like this is - You should parse the JSON:

```
require 'json'

JSON.parse '["5", "6", "12"]'
  #=> ["5", "6", "12"]
```

If you're in control of the input, I would suggest ensuring you're providing valid JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

It's very dangerous, but this does what you want:

```
eval "['5', '6', '12']"
# => ["5", "6", "12"]
```

**I wouldn't recommend this, at all** - I'd recommend working on a complete solution so the form data comes through in a manner that works with your backend.

With this approach, if someone manually updated the form field to contain, for example, `"User.destroy_all"`, that would be executed. Hence why I'd *strongly* recommend you look at a full solution to this that includes ensuring you receive the data in the correct format.

I've written this answer hoping it provides a use case in some manner, ideally to get your team to correct the data you're receiving so you can handle it safely :) Hope it's useful!